# Enabling Rewrites with XAMPP + BitNami installation of Magento 1.8.0.0

Tags: configuration

I am running XAMPP 1.8.3 + bitnami installation of Magento 1.8.0.0 on Windows 7.
I would like to get rid of index.php in the URLs I see. Here is the rest of my setup:

1) I have entered a dummy host name for my local testing environment in
   *C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts*
   so that it contains the following line and restarted Apache:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost   myhost.com
```

2) I have secured my XAMPP installation by following the setup found at
   http://myhost.com/security/index.php

3) I have had a look at C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf
   and the line that loads the Apache Rewrite module is already uncommented
   and the htdocs directory under C:\xampp already has .htaccess files
   enabled as follows (comments deleted):

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted </Directory>
</Directory>
```

1. I have enabled Rewrites in the Admin panel

> Magento Admin Panel -> System -> Configuration -> Default Config
>   -> GENERAL -> Web -> Search Engine Optimization -> Use Web Server Rewrites -> Yes

1. The various XAMPP .htaccess files for my Magento installation using bitnami now point to the following file:

> C:\xampp\apps\magento\conf\htaccess.conf

which contains the following Apache directives:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

which are the ones advertised on other posts on Stack Overflow.

However when from my main page I click  on a category I get a 404

because for instance the page http://myhost.com/magento/mycategory.html

is not found (although http://myhost.com/magento/index.php/mycategory.html is found).

What am I missing from my configuration to get mod_rewrite to work as wanted?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer to my problem.

When I installed Magento via BitNami I specified a base directory of "magento"
meaning my magento files were installed to C:\xampp\magento. Because of this,
to get rewrites working as needed and get rid of index.php, I was missing the
last step which is, inside of C:\xampp\apps\magento\conf\htaccess.conf I still
had to uncomment the following line, inside the

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

directive:

```
#RewriteBase /magento/
```

to

```
RewriteBase /magento/
```

This was all that was left. I uncommented the line and restarted Apache
and my URLs such as http://myhost.com/magento/mycategory.html
began to work.

Thanks.

Comment: OK, I've just done that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, this way, i troubleshoot problem:

```
1. Go to the directory of installation C:\xampp\apache\conf

2. Open and edit httpd.conf in a text editor

3. Find the line which contains

*\# LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so*

and (uncomment) change to

*LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so*

4. Find all occurrences of

*AllowOverride None*

and change to

*AllowOverride All*

I think it appears 2 or 3 times on the configuration file.

5. Restart xampp
```