# Magento 1.8 after migrate live server to locahost admin URL not working

Tags: admin, url, backend

I change my Magento store Live server to Localhost, and i change `core_config_data` table also that is following,

[image: change core_config_data]

I clear all `cache` files in `var/cache` folder and `session` files `var/session` folder.

Now my store `front-end` working fine. But when am enter `http://127.0.0.1/ramesh/mirror-white/admin` it move to `http://127.0.0.1/dashboard/` page.

How to solve this error...?

And thanks for advance...!

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1/ramesh/mirror-white/index.php/admin/index/index/key/2bb557d853139856a0105b02249365af/`  working, but when i click login button it shows 404 error

Comment: 1/ Do not forget the trailing slash on your URLs.
2/ Do you have mod_rewrite active on your local installation?

Comment: Thank you for replaying me @JonathanRibas 1. Now am insert `trailing slash` on all URLs. 2. Am not activate `mod_rewrite`. How can i do that...?

Comment: For `web/unsecure/base_url`, `web/unsecure/base_link_url`, `web/unsecure/base_url`, `web/secure/base_url`, `web/secure/base_link_url`.
For mod_rewrite you can check this for exemple http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2
I suggest using Wamp, it's easier for beginners.

Comment: But i'm using xampp server Jonathan.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9723/enabling-rewrites-with-xampp-bitnami-installation-of-magento-1-8-0-0

Comment: in my .httaccess i wrote this code `<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>`. You mean change this `<IfModule mod_headers.c>`  to  `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`

Comment: Check last link I send you, it seems you need to set a `RewriteBase ` because you have installed your Magento in a directory called `ramesh/mirror-white/`

Comment: Thank you very much Jonathan it working fine, But can't login.

Comment: Can you add a print of your browser's console log (with **Preserve Log** enabled) when you click on login button please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1/** You forgot the trailing slash on the above URLs in your `core_config_data`table:

`web/unsecure/base_url`

`web/unsecure/base_link_url`

`web/secure/base_url`

`web/secure/base_link_url`

**2/** If you are using Apache, enable `mod_rewrite`

**3/** Set a `RewriteBase` because you have installed your Magento in a directory called `ramesh/mirror-white/`